# Change the format of window list in tmux?

Tags: tmux

Window list, <kbd>C-a w</kbd> bound to `choose-tree -w` currently looks like this. It looks cramped when you navigate to deeply nested folders.

```
(0)  - 0: 2 windows (attached)
(1)  ├─> 1: vim- (1 panes) "vim   /home/nishant"
(2)  └─> 2: fish* (1 panes) "fish   /home/nishant"
```

Is it possible to change the format to just show only the process name?

```
(0)  - 0: 2 windows (attached)
(1)  ├─> vim- (1 panes)
(2)  └─> fish* (1 panes)
```

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick:

```
bind-key w choose-tree -F "#{window_name}"
```